# My father, a US citizen, was sponsoring me and dies before I traveled to U.S

Tags: usa, visa, us-citizens

My father went to US when I was just a year old with my other siblings. My Mom and I were left behind and many years passed. He decided to sponsor me in 2017 when i was 22. I got my DNA test in November 2018 and all was going well until he passed away in 2020 before filling financial coverage and my interview. I did some research and I read somewhere that the process is revoked and maybe another relative can take over your process, but my siblings are not willing to do that. What should I do please? My process was near completion.

Comment: What's your mother's status?

Answer (score 4):

A petition is automatically void when the petitioner dies. There are some very limited exceptions. One is if you (the beneficiary) were residing in the US at the time the petitioner died, and continues to reside in the US now, you can seek [INA 204(l) reinstatement](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-eligibility/basic-eligibility-for-section-204l-relief-for-surviving-relatives). There is also [humanitarian reinstatement](https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-eligibility/humanitarian-reinstatement) for if you have some very special humanitarian reason.

What is your mother's status? If your mother has a green card, she can petition you if you are unmarried, and remain unmarried. (If you are married, you would have to wait until she becomes a citizen before she can petition you.) The priority date of the new petition would be when your mother files it, and so the wait for visa numbers has to begin again from scratch. If your mother doesn't have a green card, and she was married to your father at the time he died, she is eligible to immigrate as a widow within 2 years of your father's death. If she already had a pending I-130 it would automatically convert to a widow I-360; if not, she can self-file a I-360.

Comment: thank you for your reply , My mother don't have green card and they were divorced when he dies . I think there is no way for this case to go further .